# Row makes Contact Form 7 fields unclickable

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

On my Wordpress site the hero section is split into 2. On the left, I have the logo, an image and optional headings. On the right, you have your contact form.

My issue is - I had to move the form down with a large margin in order to be able to fill in the form. The top input fields weren't clickable. Moving it down made them clickable again. But they are only clickable to the point where the logo row intersects with the input fields. So, it's kind of like the row is blocking the input fields. I tried adding z-index stuff in Chrome Console - but that gave me no results - except that I made the content disappear when I set it to -1.

I would like the form fields to be all clickable - and be decrease the massive margin I had to put in - but my very limited knowledge doesn't allow me to achieve this.

https://ibb.co/swcbxbc - logo row blocking form field submission.

https://ibb.co/sPbXmBk - huge margin above form

Is there anything I can do to move the form up, but have the input fields clickable.

Comment: Using position relative or absolute width z-index. Please add your code

Comment: Upon further inspection - I noticed the right column moved up behind the header row. The max-width thing did help - but only to a small extent. I also tried position and z-index on some of the elements, but without any success. As it's a WordPress template it's hard, for me at least, to isolate the exact code that's causing the problem. It's going to be much faster to rebuild the site than to further troubleshoot. The help is appreciated though.

Answer (score 1):

In the div with the class logo-container-off

put this in css

```
max-width: 300px;
```